# Infinite sum of logarithms

Tags: summation, logarithms

Is there any closed form for this expression

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\ln(n+x)
$$

Comment: Is obviously $+\infty$ (when defined).

Comment: log is defined over negative numbers, he never specified this was confined to the Reals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it as $\sum_{n=0}^k \ln(n+x)=\ln\left(\prod_{n=0}^k \left(n+x\right)\right)=\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(k+x+1)}{\Gamma(x)}\right)$. If $k$ goes to $\infty$ the expression diverges, if $x>0$ or $x$ is not equal to a negative integer.

Answer (score 7):

It's undefined whenever $x\leq 0$, and the series diverges to infinity whenever $x > 0$.

Answer (score 7):

As others correctly mentioned, the expression diverges. Yet, if necessary, you can get quite good asymptotics:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log (k+x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log k + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log (1+ \frac{x}{k}) \sim n \log n + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x}{k} = n \log n + x \log n \\
=(n+x) \log n 
$$

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to see why it diverges for $x>0$ is as follows:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ln(n+x) \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty\ln(1+x) = \infty$$
as an infinite sum of a **constant** positive argument is always infinite (I have used monotonicity of the logarithm here).

For $x\le 0$, $\ln(0+x)$ is not defined, hence the entire sum is not defined.

Comment: How about this $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(n) = \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi) $$ if we add x > 0 to the inside logarithm?

Comment: I don't understand what's written there. The sum on the left diverges as well.

Comment: Hi Bach, I got that from here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSeries.html. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nguyen: from the page you linked: *Note that the first two of these are divergent in the classical sense, but converge when interpreted as zeta-regularized sums.*

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325169/zeta-regulated-product-solving-without-the-zeta-function?rq=1. An elementary solution, but not generalised by x.

Answer (score 0):

The regularized value of this sum is

$\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{2 \pi }{\Gamma (x)^2}\right)$