# An interesting integral $\int_0^{\infty}\{e^x\}-\frac {1}{2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

So I recently thought of this random integral, as I was thinking of integrals that have nice cancellation properties involving the fractional part. I believe I have an answer but my method is rather non-rigorous as I do not prove convergence, nor even know if it converges.
Here is what I did:

Let $$J=\int_0^{\infty}\{e^x\}-\frac {1}{2}dx$$
Expressing it in terms of the floor function and noticing that for $x\in(\log(n),\log(n+1))$, you have $\lfloor e^x \rfloor=n$ yields

$J=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\log(n)}^{\log(n+1)}(e^x-\lfloor e^x\rfloor-\frac {1}{2} )  dx=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\log(n)}^{\log(n+1)}(e^x-n-\frac {1}{2} )  dx
\\= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+(n+\frac{1}{2})\log(\frac{n}{n+1}))$

This can be expressed as

$$J= \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N((n-\frac{1}{2})\log(n)-(n+\frac{1}{2})\log(n+1)+\log(n)+1)$$
The first two terms are telescoping which gives

$J=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\log(N!)+N-(N+\frac{1}{2})\log(N+1))$

$ =\lim_{N\to\infty}(N\log(N)+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi N)-(N+\frac{1}{2})\log(N+1))$  (using Stirling's formula)

$ = \lim_{N\to\infty}((N+\frac{1}{2})\log(N)-(N+\frac{1}{2})\log(N+1))+\frac{1}{2}\log(2 \pi)=\frac{1}{2}\log(2 \pi)+\log(\frac{1}{e})=\frac{1}{2}\log(2 \pi)-1.$

It would be much appreciated if anyone could rectify any mistakes I made, make this rigorous and/or correct me on why the integral diverges.

Comment: Your calculation is correct. Alternatively, let $x = \log (t + 1)$, then your integral becomes $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\left\{ {t + 1} \right\} - \frac{1}{2}}}{{t + 1}}\mathrm{d}t}  =  - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\frac{1}{2} - \left\{ t \right\}}}{{t + 1}}\mathrm{d}t} .
$$ Now have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668035).

Comment: One way to check convergence is to compare this integral to the error associated with a trapezoid rule.  It shows that this integral converges if and only if $\sum_n (n+1)(\ln(n+1)-\ln(n))^3$ does, whose terms are asymptotic to the terms $\sum_n \frac1{n^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generalization
to an increasing function
instead of $e^x$.
An expression is derived for
$\int_0^{\infty}(\{f(x)\}-\frac12)dx$
which,
when specialized to
$f(x)=e^x$,
shows that the iimit
does exist.

The expression for
$J(n)
=\int_0^{f^{(-1)}(n))}(\{f(x)\}-\frac12)dx$
is
$\int_{m}^{n}yg'(y)dy-(n+\frac12)x_n+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}
+c$
where $f(x_k)=k$
and $g$ is the inverse function of $f$
and $c$ and $m$ are constants independent
if $n$.

I would not be surprised
if the expression for
$J(n)$
could be simplified
by using some properties
of $f(x)$.

Here is the
moderately messy derivation.

Consider
$J
=\int_0^{\infty}(\{f(x)\}-\frac12)dx
=\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_0^t(\{f(x)\}-\frac12)dx
$.

Suppose
$f(x) \ge, 0,
f'(x) > 0,
f''(x) > 0,
f(x)\to \infty
$
as $x \to \infty$,
and $f$ has no singularities.

What can be said about $J$?

Let $g$ be the inverse of $f$
so
$f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x
$.

Let $x_n$
be such that
$f(x_n)=n$
for positive integral $n$
and let $m$ be the smallest such that
$f(x_m) > 0$.

Consider

$\begin{array}\\
J(n)
&=\int_{x_m}^{x_n}(\{f(x)\}-\frac12)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}(\{f(x)\}-\frac12)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}(f(x)-\lfloor f(x)\rfloor-\frac12)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}(f(x)-k-\frac12)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}f(x)dx-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}(k+\frac12)dx\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(x)dx-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(x_{k+1}-x_k)(k+\frac12)\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(x)dx-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}k(x_{k+1}-x_k)-\frac12\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(x_{k+1}-x_k)\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(x)dx-\frac12(x_n-x_m)-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}kx_{k+1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}kx_k\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(x)dx-\frac12(x_n-x_m)-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(k+1-1)x_{k+1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}kx_k\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(x)dx-\frac12(x_n-x_m)-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}(k+1)x_{k+1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}x_{k+1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}kx_k\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(x)dx-\frac12(x_n-x_m)-\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}kx_{k}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}x_{k+1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}kx_k\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(x)dx-\frac12(x_n-x_m)-nx_n+mx_m+\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}x_{k+1}\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}f(g(y))g'(y)dy-\frac12(x_n-x_m)-nx_n+mx_m+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}
\qquad x=g(y), dx=g'(y) dy\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}yg'(y)dy-\frac12(x_n-x_m)-nx_n+mx_m+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}yg'(y)dy-(n+\frac12)x_n+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}+(m+\frac12)x_m\\
\end{array}
$

If
$f(x)=e^x,
g(y)=\ln(y),
g'(y)=\dfrac1{y},
x_n=\ln(n)
$
so
$m=1, x_m=0$

$\begin{array}\\
J(n)
&=\int_{m}^{n}yg'(y)dy-(n+\frac12)x_n+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}x_{k}+(m+\frac12)x_m\\
&=\int_{m}^{n}dy-(n+\frac12)\ln(n)+\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\ln(k)+(m+\frac12)\ln(m)\\
&=n-m-(n+\frac12)\ln(n)+\ln(n!)-\ln(m!)+(m+\frac12)\ln(m)\\
&=n-(n+\frac12)\ln(n)+(n+\frac12)\ln(n)-n+c+O(\frac1{n})
\qquad c=\frac12\ln(\pi)+\text{terms involving }m\\
&=c\\
\end{array}
$

So
$J(n)$
does approach a limit as
$n \to \infty$.